# Spring data jpa query name

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I would like to use the built in query creation from method names, for example:

```
public Person findByFirstName(String firstName);
```

But I want to mark specific queries "for update" meaning to use:

```
public Person findByFirstNameForUpdate(String firstName);
```

Is there a way to make it work? I know I can create a new repository "PersonRepositoryForUpdate" but can I use the same repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `@Query` annotation above the method and use any query and any name for the method.

```
@Query("select ...")
public Person findGiveAnyName(String firstName);
```

The query can be written in JPQL or SQL.

Comment: thanks, I know I can do this but is there a way to use the automatic query that spring data gives?